# Haskell 32-bit program freezes on a 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc

I'm using the GHC to build a haskell pogram for Windows with help of a speciefic (Haskell-)Library which is called citeproc-hs. On a 32Bit-Windows XP machine the application works just fine whereas on another Windows 7 64Bit environment (tested on 3 different PCs) a "function of that library reading a speciefic file (a "style" file) mentioned above just freezes without any error message. I use the same .exe file and nevertheless there is a different behaviour I cannot explain.

Are there maybe some known problems concerning 32Bit Haskell - compilations in an 64Bit environment or does anyone has an idea how I could solve this strange problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It may be related to the fact the GHC always generates 32 bit executables for Windows. There may be crashs if you try to run a 32 bit executable with a 64 bit library.

Comment: How is it difficult tell what is being asked/how is it not a real question?

Answer (score 1):

I use GHC on 64 bit windows in production, and we don't seem to have any issues.

I would suggest upgrading. If the behavior continues, report a bug against GHC.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run it interpreted mode? Probably citeproc-hs is guilty. Does it contains any C code? And of course, you may comment out line-by-line and see what goes wrong. Does "hello world" runs fine?